# Why i am getting a wrong answer towards this probability question related to Law of Probability?

Tags: probability

> Question
>
> If we have two cube ,we painted the cube with blue and pink colour only
>
> If we painted the 4 sides with  pink colour and other 2 side with blue
>
> color
>
> How many sides we will paint pink color in second cube.Given probabity for both cubes have same color is 1/3

Solution:Approach(I Followed)

$P(\text{Both Cubes Having Same Color})=P(\text{Pink In First Cube})\cdot(\text{Pink In Second Cube})
+P(\text{Blue In First Cube})\cdot P(\text{Blue In Second Cube})=(4/6 \cdot x/6)+(2/6\cdot y/6)=1/3$

Solving the equation i get $x = 0$ and $y =6$ .Thus, all the 6 sides will be painted blue.

> Is my answer or the approach correct?
>   Ans is 1/3

Comment: This requires some clarifications. Most importantly, $\frac13$ is not a possible answer to the question "How many sides ...", the answer to which must be an integer. Here's my interpretation of what you wrote so you can check whether that's what you intended: You have two six-sided dice, you paint one in pink on $4$ sides and in blue on $2$ sides, and then you want to paint the second die such that when you roll both dice, the probability for two sides of the same colour to come up is $\frac13$?

Comment: @joriki Yes,Ans will not come 1/3.May be the book has typo mistake and Yes u interpreted right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct; you need $x=0$ and $y=6$ to make the probability of rolling identical colours come out to $\frac13$. Thus all six faces of the second die need to be painted blue (not pink, as you wrote underneath the calculation).